# How to infer type from a schema generated by a generic function in zod?

Tags: typescript, generics, zod

I have a generic function which generated a very simple schema.

```
const LeafSchema = <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(valueSchema: T) { 
    return z.object({ value: valueSchema })
}
```

Now I want to infer the type of this generated Schema, with using ReturnType, but also I have to use a generic, if not value will be `any`.

```
type Leaf<T extends z.ZodTypeAny> = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof LeafSchema<T>>>
const getLeafValue = <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(leaf: Leaf<T>) => leaf.value
```

However, I still get `any` when calling getLeafValue with `{ 'value': 123 }`. I understand that something wrong with my generics, but i'm not sure how to fix it. Sadly I haven't found much about generics with zod...

Heres the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=10&ssc=30&pln=10&pc=14#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7wAyApgIaYDKlAFsyK3AC8cADwAVOMwAeMZjWJ0UAOgBaJMQE8wzAII0NAPgAUAN1YAbAK7MuvfgC44YgJRCDyiACMAVs0owjJDMrZkdg61s%20ATRnChgtZjgWdnFJGTkFZTViTW09QyFlYBpMZigRACVmGEsoGlzmEXjtCEwktk4eKPEDXrIAen64YeGAPQB%20Cmp6eABzauTMADULa0LU6Vl5RWRVdQT843MOx0We10F3Y-YlcOYp2gY4WSfhJHw7-EcARgAmAGZ0FRHvBgoV5jBFisQkYXjBYoMRmNJoiAJJwADurBo8BgEDg3FYJkSNEsIE8ZQJZXuwJmz2YDF%20hXenx%20APQcFYijOpPJZXciOIEAZnPMdHxNAg8Ax0AA1kA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using `<T>` with `ZodType<T>` instead of `<T extends ZodAnyType>` with `<T>`. Almost works as intended, as undefined will be return beside number in the `getLeafValue` function.

```
type Leaf<T> = z.infer<ReturnType<typeof LeafSchema<z.ZodType<T>>>>
type NumberLeaf = Leaf<number>
//    ^? { value: number }

const getLeafValue = <T>(leaf: Leaf<T>) => leaf.value
const test = { 'value': 123 }
const val = getLeafValue(test)
//     ^? { value: number | undefined }
```

Wrapping the `z.infer` with a `Required<>` would fix it in this example, but would make optional value (when present) also required. So, that only half the solution...

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgFBkDGEAdgM7wAyApgIaYDKlAFsyK3AC8cADwAVOMwAeMZjWJ0UAOgBaJMQE8wzAII0NAPgAUAN1YAbAK7MuvfgC44YgJRCDyiACMAVs0owjJDMrZkdg61s%20ATRnChgtZjgWdnF3YWQlYBpMZigRACVmGEsoGk1tEXjtCEwktk4eKJEMtWJy5lSDLrIqxIA5SxBPXOTa4VGRGkHhqAMyAHp5uGW4AD0AfgpqengAcyLRgDULayFRMWNzescJi9dBdyv2JXDmKloGOFlP4SR8V-wjgAjAAmADM6HeOzgwTO%20xgRxOzCM3xgsUWK2WGy2H3gqJBZz%20AOB4PQcFYigmUyGuXcQA)

Comment: Am I missing something or can't you just assert non-null? https://tsplay.dev/NB8G4W

Comment: Works for this case, but `{ value: undefined }` or `{ value: null }` would return `never` instead of `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const LeafSchema = <T extends z.ZodTypeAny>(valueSchema: T) => z.object({ value: valueSchema })

const LeafRefSchema = LeafSchema(z.string())

type LeafefSchemaInterface = z.infer<typeof LeafRefSchema>
```